# How to make dock-able plugins for NetBeans IDE in Java?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I have created one analogue clock with Java. But i want to make it dock-able in NetBeans IDE (like shown in the screen shot).

- like the left side navigator, files, bottom tasks are hidden, once i press it it shows in left or bottom

Any help on this, how can i tell my NetBeans plugin to act like dock-able? After making it working i would like to publish it to the community plugin.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not too complicated using the NetBeans Rich Client Platform.  Follow this tutorial - http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-paintapp.html#impMod

Basically, you'll create a ClockTopComponent using the wizard.  [TopComponents](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-windows/org/openide/windows/TopComponent.html) automatically get nice windowing features for free, like docking, hiding, tiling, etc.

[FAQs about TopComponent](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqWindowsTopComponent)